# How can I save csv fill in snappy compressed format pyspark - 2.0+ version

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying the below code -

```
riders.write.csv(path="/loudacre/devices4_csv", sep=",", mode="overwrite", compression="snappy")
```

Error - 
18/12/22 13:54:38 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 10)
java.lang.RuntimeException: native snappy library not available: this version of libhadoop was built without snappy support.
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.checkNativeCodeLoaded(SnappyCodec.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.getCompressorType(SnappyCodec.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(CodecPool.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec$Util.createOutputStreamWithCodecPool(CompressionCodec.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.createOutputStream(SnappyCodec.java:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$$anonfun$createOutputStream$1.apply(CodecStreams.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$$anonfun$createOutputStream$1.apply(CodecStreams.scala:84)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.(CSVFileFormat.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(CSVFileFormat.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)

Comment: You would need to paste the complete error trace log. Its not clear what the error is for.

Comment: I am not able to paste full error. It seems mainly due to Snappy not being supported -

Comment: Is there something missing in my syntax, as the same syntax worked for gzip and bzip2 compression

Answer (score 0):

Check if snappy is installed. 
`hadoop checknative -a`

If its not installed:
`yum install snappy snappy-devel`

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_command-line-installation/content/install_compression_libraries.html

If its installed but if its not being picked by spark, you can manually add these to spark-default.conf. You may to change the paths depending on your locations.

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/snappy*.jar
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native
```